# Why Activity closes as it starts?

Tags: android-studio

I have a activity in Android Studio and the app closes whenever I start that activity. Can you please check what's the problem.

```
public class AddEx extends AppCompatActivity {

public int max, min;

public int w,m;

public ArrayList<Object>exer = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<Integer>ans = new ArrayList<>();
public ListView ex = findViewById(R.id.Exerciselist);
public ArrayAdapter<Object> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, exer);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_ex);
    
    start();
}

public void start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i<=9; i++)
    {


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int Token = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra(Add_Subtract.MSG));

        if(Token == 1)
        {
            max = 9;
            min = 1;
        }
        else if(Token == 2)
        {
            max = 99;
            min = 10;
        }
        else if(Token == 3)
        {
            max = 999;
            min = 100;
        }
        else if(Token == 4)
        {
            max = 9999;
            min = 1000;
        }
        else if(Token == 5)
        {
            max = 99999;
            min = 10000;
        }

        w = ((int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min));
        m = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
        ans.add(w+m);
        exer.add(w+" + "+m);
    }
    ex.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}

public void answers(View view)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<=9; i++)
    {
        Object ques = exer.get(i);
        exer.set(i, ques+" = "+ans.get(i));
    }
    ex.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

}

The function answers is button controlled. I want the start function to run as the activity starts but as soon the activity starts, the app closes. I request you to tell the problem
Thanks

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: Nothing, the app just closes when redirected to this activity

Comment: You will have some error in the logcat buddy !

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.exercise/com.example.exercise.AddEx}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public ListView ex = findViewById(R.id.Exerciselist);`

Remove this line and add it to either `onCreate()` or `start()`

You are initialising `Exerciselist` even before the layout is initialised, so the app doesn't know what it is, that's why it crashes

Comment: I moved it to start() but still it crashed

Comment: but it didn't. Can you tell a way by which I can put it in  onCreate() and access it from other methods or a way by which I can use a button without making a method

Comment: Now the simple problem is I cannot access the list from the answers function,  do you have solution for that

Comment: add it to onCreate instead of start, that way it will be accessible to all functions

Comment: But it isn't accessible to different methods

Comment: add it to every single method then, that will work

Answer (score 0):

> i noted 2 problems:

> **1** : you attached by id not in onCreate/Function.

> **2**: you attached the adapter to an **empty array called "exer"** - thats why it returns an null Exception.

```
public class AddEx extends AppCompatActivity {

public int max, min;

public int w,m;

public ArrayList<Object>exer = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<Integer>ans = new ArrayList<>();
public ListView ex;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_ex);
```

**// move the list view attach to here**

```
    ex = findViewById(R.id.Exerciselist);
    start();
  }
   public void start()
   {
    for (int i = 0; i<=9; i++)
   {


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int Token = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra(Add_Subtract.MSG));

    if(Token == 1)
    {
        max = 9;
        min = 1;
    }
    else if(Token == 2)
    {
        max = 99;
        min = 10;
    }
    else if(Token == 3)
    {
        max = 999;
        min = 100;
    }
    else if(Token == 4)
    {
        max = 9999;
        min = 1000;
    }
    else if(Token == 5)
    {
        max = 99999;
        min = 10000;
    }

    w = ((int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min));
    m = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    ans.add(w+m);
    exer.add(w+" + "+m);
}
```

**// move the array adapter here**

```
  ArrayAdapter<Object> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, exer);
  ex.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
 }
```

> about the code blow - it doesnt clear when do you what it to run' and by the way you dont even call this function anywhere in the code....

```
public void answers(View view)
{
   for (int i = 0; i<=9; i++)
   {
    Object ques = exer.get(i);
    exer.set(i, ques+" = "+ans.get(i));
   }
   ex.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
  }
```